# JPA Mapping native query with collection of Integers

Tags: hibernate, jpa, collections, mapping, native

I have a native query that return a result like this :

```
id_a | id_b
-----+-----
   1 |   1
   1 |   2
   1 |   3
```

I would like to map those results into a single object like this :

```
public class Result {
  private Integer idA;
  private Set<Integer> idBSet;
  ...
  (getters and setters)
}
```

I didn't found any solution to do that mapping. I use hibernate and I tried sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY); without success.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do it yourself, in your code as you go through the results and build up the map. It's only the same as expecting a JPA implementation to do it for you, and there is nothing in the JPA spec to impose that on an implementation